# Insert After specific child of Parent jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a set of elements within a parent that i'm trying to insert another element into. I'm getting the amount of elements using .children().length. This works according to plan but i don't know what to look for when trying to insert after a specific element. I'm assuming i can use insertAfter() when i have the element, but how do i go about cycling through the children elements to reach the correct one.

JS

```
var middleCount = ($(".parent").children().length) / 2;
```

HTML

```
<div class = "parent">
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `:eq()`...[docs](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: after which element you want to insert?

Comment: i'm looking to insert it into the middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
var midElement = $(".parent").children().eq(middleCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var templength = $(".parent").children().length;
var temp = parseInt(templength/2);
//due to floting point
$(".parent p").eq(temp-1).after("<p>Rahi</p>")
```